# Unable to Access System Variables in Vite Library (Mode) Installed in Own Project

Tags: environment-variables, vite

I've encountered an issue while trying to access system variables within a Vite library build that I've published privately. Here's the problem: after installing the Vite package into my own project, I'm unable to access the system variables as expected.

Here's the relevant code from my Vite library build:

```
const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '')
//...
define: { __APP_ENV__: JSON.stringify(env.APP_ENV) },
```

I'm using `loadEnv()` to load the environment variables, and then defining `__APP_ENV__` using define in my Vite configuration.

However, even though this works fine within the library build, when I install the library in my project and try to access `__APP_ENV__`, it returns undefined. It seems like the system variables are not being properly accessed or defined in my project using the installed Vite library.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!